# Failed to notify dependency resolution listener

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

I tried to run my project for first time but I faced this error:

> Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
>   Problems reading data
>   from Binary store in
>   C:\Users\Ghaem\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle9202596089529693792.bin
>   (exist: true)

[image]

I've tried changing version of gradle to all available version with no luck.

My Project (root) build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My App build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.itechnotion.wpnews"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "f893b120-b601-41e5-b0e3-715626efe0a3",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
            aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8489. The solution seems to be to run the `clean` and `build` tasks. Also please don't write a custom `clean` task. Just apply the `base` plugin (`apply plugin: 'base'`) which already defines these tasks

Comment: @smac89 Thank you. This worked. Know I faced a new error: `Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Program type already present:
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzet

Update **`classpath`**

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

    }
```

**OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin**

```
   classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'
```

Use **`implementation`** instead of `compile`.

```
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

You are using very old versions. If you want to use latest then libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX).

AndroidX replaces the original support library APIs with packages in the androidx namespace. Read official guideline about [**`AndroidX Overview`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

```
compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
```

Your **`appcompat:appcompat`** & **`constraintlayout`** will

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: When I update classpath I see errors like this: `Could not find com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.6.1.`

Comment: @Ghaem use `classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'`

Answer (score 0):

if you have the old project and cased by this error. my project was not building after upgradation to flamingo. So i tried this.

1. Go to file than project structure than find gradle settings changed it to use JDK 11.
   [image: jdk location]
2. changing the gradle version of the project to the newest version 6.2.1 on the project structure options.

[image]