# Execution failed for task ':wsdl2java' Failed to notify dependency resolution listener

Tags: java, gradle, wsdl, build.gradle, wsdl2java

I'm new to gradle. In order to remove 'no.nils.wsdl2java' deprecated plugin I replaced it with com.github.bjornvester.wsdl2java.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.6.1'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
maven {
            url "http://..."
            credentials {
                ...
            }
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:4.0")
        classpath group: 'com.yahoo.platform.yui', name: 'yuicompressor', version: '2.4.7'
        **classpath("com.github.bjornvester:wsdl2java-gradle-plugin:2.0.2")**
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2"
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.1.4"
    }


}
...
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
//apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.bjornvester.wsdl2java'

wsdl2java {
    generatedSourceDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/java")
    wsdlDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources")
    includes = [
             ...
    ]
    cxfVersion = "4.0.2" 
}
```

My gradle version is 7.0

I'm getting an error that does not tell me exactly what went wrong.

Execution failed for task ':wsdl2java'.
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'

Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository {artifactory} to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.

But I already have  allowInsecureProtocol = true added

Any idea how could I fix my build.gradle?

I've changed my old task version

```
wsdl2java {
    generatedWsdlDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/java")
    wsdlDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources")
    wsdlsToGenerate = [
            ...
    ]
    locale = Locale.ENGLISH
}

wsdl2javaExt {
    cxfVersion = "3.5.5"
}
```

to this one compatible with com.github.bjornvester

```
wsdl2java {
    generatedSourceDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/java")
    wsdlDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources")
    includes = [
             ...
    ]
    cxfVersion = "4.0.2" 
}
```

Did I not replace no.nils.wsdl2java with the corect dependency ?

I saw [Failed to notify dependency resolution listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434382/failed-to-notify-dependency-resolution-listener) but I do not have the same dependencies in my project